# Extract innerHTML from span[class]

Tags: javascript, jquery

so my code is something along the lines of:

```
<table><tr><td class="tdclass1">



$('#nameoftable tr').each(function(){
  tdclass1 = $(this).find(".classname").html();
  if (tdclass1:contains('classname'))
//do something here
});
```

What I want to do is simply extract the inner HTML of this specific span.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: `tdclass1:contains('classname')` is not valid JavaScript. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$("#nameoftable .tdclass1 span.classname").each(function () {
    var html = $(this).html();

});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#nameoftable .tdclass1 span.classname').each (function (idx, elem) {
  console.log ($(elem).html ()); 
});
```

Comment: `classname.span`: Don't you mean `span.classname`?

Answer (score 2):

Try the `innerHTML` property :-)

Comment: The answer is correct, if Barney want to get the innerHTML of a span he have to use the innerHTML property.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#nameoftable .tdclass1').each(function(){
  var my_html = this.innerHTML;
});
```

Comment: This is actually the best solution, since `$(this).html()` does the exact same thing (there are no bugs to fix in this case). Therefore, `this.innerHTML` is much better, since it is much faster.